# VC++ 10 project allocates too much memory for objects

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-management

I'm using VC++ 10 for a C++ project I'm working on and for some reason whenever I allocate an object the system allocates 4kb of memory for it (even if the object is a few bytes long).

To sum up:

- Using new/malloc to allocate small objects results into the allocation of **4kb for each object.**
- I verified the project settings with a new project and there are no differences.
- The project uses an external C dll and includes a header file containing declarations for the exported functions and structures of that dll.
- Test system is Win7 x64 but the application is compiled for x86

The project is quite large, but I haven't found any directives telling the system to allocate that much memory and I can verify that the parameter passed to new/malloc is the correct size of the object.

Note that this happens for all objects/structures within my project.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you building in debug mode?

Comment: How did you observe that 4kb value ? I strongly suspect this is just normal memory paging behavior.

Comment: Can you post source code for your memory allocation?

Comment: `Can you post source code for your allocation?` and also how you do the measurement of the memory allocation

Comment: hi, the issue exists both in debug and release mode. Memory allocations look like: SomeObject * obj = new SomeObject() or malloc(sizeof(somestruct)).

Comment: 4k is the size of a system page (on your system) and is likely the smallest amount of memory that the operating system can allocate.

Comment: I debugged the application and stepped through the allocation function, observed it in task manager and procexp

Comment: "Thank you in advance". For what?. You haven't asked a question.

Comment: @user1400757 Try it for two objects. Chances are you will see no change in memory consumption.

Comment: yeah 4kb is the default system page for this application, however its not the minimum

Comment: `external C dll` memory leak cannot be handled. One tips for checking memory leak.  Start task manager, see memory uses and do some work. If the memory allocation doesn't back to previous position it might have memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are on x86, memory can only be given to a memory allocator implementation in page sized chunks or larger, and the default page size is 4 kilobytes.

You will see a 4kb difference in process working set for the first object, but you should see nothing for subsequent allocations until that page is used up.

(This assumes you are building in release mode. In debug mode, the CRT may use more memory per object for canaries/bounds checking)

Comment: Actually this is what i was expecting, but it allocates 4kb for each object

Comment: Well then, [status-norepro] here.

Comment: ok, it appears that application verifier is loaded with the executable. this is causing the issues